Unable to deploy project in Glassfish
I am getting an error message that says "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server" when I click on the "Add and Remove" button in Glassfish for deploying my project.
I am using java 8, eclipse 2020 and glassfish 5. The project is a newly created Dynamic Web project. I tried converting it to a maven based project and updating the settings but that did not work. I also tried checking the checkbox 'Dynamic web project' in project facets but the box gets unchecked when I click OK.
I have been trying to fix this for two days now and don't know what else to do. Please ask me for any other details that you want to know about my setup.

Hi, do you use this Eclipse IDE plugin for GlassFish: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/omnifish-tools-eclipse-glassfish? Did you also try with GlassFish 7?
